# unittest in python: ignore an import from the code I want to test

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a python program that imports pythoncom (and uses pythoncom.CoCreateInstance from it). I want to create a unittest for the program logic without it importing pythoncom (so I can run the test on Linux as well).

What options are there? Can I do it without modifying the system under test?

What I found so far:

```
sys.modules["pythoncom"] = "test"
import module_that_imports_pythoncom
```

My problem with it is if I have:

```
from pythoncom.something import something
```

I'll get:

```
ImportError: No module named something.something
```

And `sys.modules["something.something"]` or `sys.modules["pythoncom.something.something"]` doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put `import pythoncom` into a `try except` block.

Comment: I said I don't want to modify the system under test, it should not work if it can't find pythoncom. What I want is in my tests to ignore or mock the pythoncom import so I can mock some functions from it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run tests and they actually are OS-dependent, you might want to use these decorators for example:

```
def run_only(func, predicate):
    if predicate():
        return func
    else:
        def f(*args, **kwargs): pass
        return f


def run_only_for_linux(func):
    pred = lambda: sys.platform == 'linux2'
    return run_only(func, pred)


@run_only_for_linux
def hello_linux():
    """docstring"""
    print("hello linux")
```

In this way you declare that the test only runs on linux without adding ugly complexity in the test itself.

Comment: I'm getting the following running this code: TypeError: f() takes no arguments (1 given)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what if you modify `PYTHONPATH` in the tests, and make a new package on the filesystem in a testing directory called `pythoncom` with the necessary subdirectories?

Comment: This would work but I'm looking on a simple solution, can I mark this module as already imported from my tests? Or replace it with a mock? I don't want to be os dependant when running the tests.